# What should i do with links returned after calling REST API?

Tags: rest, api, restful-architecture, api-design, hateoas

I am building front end for a project. I am using Angular2 for the front end. The API i must call is RESTful. It implements HATEOAS. When i call an API it gives me data and links. These links are from HATEOAS. When i call the API should i save the data as well as HATEOAS links in a model or just the data. For example: the API call: `localhost:/api/users/` gives me following response:

```
{
 "id":"105",
 "name": "John"
 "salary": "10000",
 "links": {
         "getSalary": {
         "method": "GET",
         "url": "/api/users/105/salary",
         "headers": [
           "X-Auth-Token",
           "Content-Type"
          ],
         "body": null
}
```

So what do i do with the links part? Should i save the links in the model at front end or just the relevant data like id, name, salary, etc?
The links part will have other links also explaining POST, PUT, DELETE, etc links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should i save the links in the model at front end

You should **not** save the URL to your data model on the front end. Either:

1. use the URL to get more data that you need; or
2. throw it away if you don't need it

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what the use case is.

- if you just need to display the name, you don't need to do anything;
- if you need to also display the salary, save the name and then "follow" the link to get the salary (it's a bit strange because it looks like you already have it...although you probably need a CurrencyISO of some sorts, too);
- if for example you're in a list scenario, and you need to display just the name for now, but you might need to display the salary if you drill down into a user, you could save the link and only follow it when needed.